# Flush logs before Lambda finish executing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, typescript, logging, aws-lambda

I am writing a logger service in NodeJS/Typescript targeting for AWS Lambda, and I noticed there are four ways to complete the Lambda function:

1. Default termination. All callbacks are finished and Lambda will finish executing.
2. Error. There's an uncaught exception or unhandled rejection and it crashes Lambda and calls `process.exit()`.
3. Timeout. Lambda runs more than the time that the developer specified.
4. Controlled termination. Lambda finish executing by calling `context.done()`, `context.succeed()` or `context.fail()`. This is not suggested any more, should use `callback()` instead.

I want my logger to be able to flush all the logs no matter how Lambda finish executing, and here is what I implemented with different ways of terminations:

1. Default termination. I wrapped the handler and the callback function to flush the logs before calling the callback function, and it worked perfectly.

   ```
   wrap(fn) {
       return () => {
           // Wrap the callback function
           let callbackFunc = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
           let wrappedCallback = this.wrapCallback(callbackFunc);
           arguments[arguments.length - 1] = wrappedCallback;

           return fn.apply(this, arguments);
       };
   }

   wrapCallback(fn) {
       return () => {
           logger.flush();
           return fn.apply(this, arguments);
       };
   ```
2. Error. I added code to catch the errors and process.exit, and it worked.

   ```
   process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
       logErrorAndFlusgLogs();
   }).on('uncaughtException', err => {
       logErrorAndFlusgLogs();
   }).on('exit', (code) => {
       logErrorAndFlusgLogs();
   });
   ```

But for 'Timeout' and 'Controlled termination', none of the function works above and I couldn't find a way to catch it and flush the logs before Lambda finish executing, any idea on how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timeouts are handled by the lambda container. There is currently no signal or callback, so for that case your best bet is to set a timer to expire a few moments before the timeout value to flush the logs and stop the lambda yourself.

For the controlled termination cases, you can monkey patch `context.done`, `context.succeed` and `context.fail`:

```
const { done, succeed, fail } = context;

context.done = (...params) => {
    logErrorAndFlushLogs();
    done(...params);
};

context.succeed = (...params) => {
    logErrorAndFlushLogs();
    succeed(...params);
};

context.fail = (...params) => {
    logErrorAndFlushLogs();
    fail(...params);
};
```